# Python - space for xlabels

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to set space for xlabels please?
I read https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html but I don't understant. I use matplotlib.pyplot. Thank you

```
plt.xlabel(r'Měsíc', fontsize=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Usually it should be enough to call `plt.tight_layout()` (without any further arguments).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Correct - I'll formulate better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `plt.tight_layout()` it is used for exactly such problems. Additionally if its automatic algorithm to distribute everything nicely on the canvas, it as a kwarg `rect`, which needs a list of `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]` values defining the space of the figure to be used for the (sub)plot(s), e.g.

```
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, .1, 1, .95)
```

It should be called at the end of the plot creation, right before `plt.show()` if your script needs the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your response and please `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]` are values of field under the graph? So in my case xmin = 0, ymin = -20, xmax = 12, ymax = -10 ? My code ended by 'plt.savefig(name.png)', so it should be placed before or I have to add `plt.show`?

Comment: No, sorry, it should be called before any savefig, too. And the values are in the range of 0 ... 1, so as a fraction of the figure size (figure is the white sheet where your plots, legends, titles etc are drawn onto) - independant of the absolute width and height of the figure.

Comment: This error message tells you that `nrows_list` is empty and therefore `max()` cannot compute a result. It has nothing to do with the usage of `plt.tight_layout()` (which you should test first without `rect`, as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest correctly pointed out.)